# Finding Eigenvector of repeated eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find Eigenvector of following matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}

I solved the characteristic of the the above matrix  is \begin{equation}  (1-\lambda)^{3}=0 \end{equation}

Comment: You should say (instead) "I found the characteristic polynomial of the above matrix, so its eigenvalues are roots of $(1-\lambda)^3 = 0$."

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ then the eigenspace is given by the kernel of $A-\lambda I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

In your case, you have just the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ and you compute the kernel of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}-1\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: I solved that, i got three eigenvector which are$ {\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}  } $  
  
but i also want to find jordan canonical form of above matrix and for that i have to find a matrix T such that $ \begin{equation} J=T^{-1}AT\end{equation} $

Comment: @prakashchandel You only have two linearly independent eigenvectors. The third is a scalar multiple of the second. Also, if you just need to find $J$, you can do that without computing $T$.

Comment: thanks,but if  we consider other set of eigenvector $ {\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}  } $  then we can find a matrix which is invertible.

Comment: How do you compute your eigenvectors? $(0,0,1)$ is **not** an eigenvector.